# Disable a device on boot

Tags: boot, xinput

I am trying to disable a device at boot.

I have put my commands in the `/etc/rc.local` file (before the `exit 0`) but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is how my file looks like :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo "OK 1" >> /tmp/rclocal_test

xinput disable "N-trig DuoSense"

xinput disable "N-trig DuoSense Pen"

echo "OK 2" >> /tmp/rclocal_test

exit 0
```

In my `rclocal_test` file, I only get `OK 1`.

When I execute `rc.local` from shell once the system is started, it works fine.

I also tried to put the commands in the `gnome-session-properties` thing but nothing happens either.

I am suspecting it is a problem of timing (maybe I cannot execute `xinput disable` at that time ?). Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for users who use latter versions of Ubuntu.

Temporarily for currently session you can just

`xinput disable "DEVICE NAME"`

If you put this anywhere inside a startup script file for example in directory `/etc/init.d`, you need to find out where is the correct point or your command will be executed before xinput started which does nothing of course.

So the easiest way for permanent effect is

[image]

Comment: Will it disable it also on login screen?

Answer (score 0):

From `man xinput`, we see:

```
NAME
   xinput - utility to configure and test X input devices
```

`xinput` will only work ***after*** the ***user*** has started the X Window System.

The environment seen by `/etc/rc.local` does not include the X Window System. The reason that your script does not complete can be seen by running `xinput --list` in a CTRL-ALT-F1 login:

```
walt@spong:~(0)$ xinput --list
Unable to connect to X server
walt@spong:~(1)$
```