# I am unable to connect to X server

Tags: xinput

I am running lubuntu and I am trying to disable my touchscreen but when I try using xinput the computer says "unable to connect to X server

Comment: When, in the system startup, do you try (and what, exactly, did you "try"? What error?). The X server starts very late in the process.

Answer (score 3):

If you do it from tty, you should provide DISPLAY env variable

```
lol4t0@lol4t0-nix:~$ DISPLAY=:1 xinput 
Unable to connect to X server
lol4t0@lol4t0-nix:~$ DISPLAY=:0 xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8006:00 06CB:CD8B Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8006:00 06CB:CD8B Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ sof-hda-dsp Headset Jack                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```